# Are there any update frameworks for iOS apps?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to be able to update my app from within the app itself.  I know Sparkle works for Mac Apps but I can't seem to find any for iOS.

**Edit:**  I am not asking how to bypass the review process.  I was thinking that there might be frameworks similar to Clutch.io that allow updates to images/documents/etc from within the app.  Or things like UrbanAirship that manage in app purchase data that allows an app to be extended from the app itself.

Comment: ...and bypass the review process? You seriously expect to be able to do that?

Comment: I don't expect to be able to bypass the review process, however I would like to be able to update anything that I can whether it is data or images or what-not.

Comment: And for whoever voted me down, this is a valid question.  I didn't ask how to break the rules or how to bypass the review process, I asked how to update the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't replace your app with an updated one (except through the App Store) and you can't replace parts of your app with updated parts (that would make your app's code signature invalid); you can only update stuff that's outside of your app's bundle.

Comment: That would be, for example data you write to /Documents, /Library, etc.

Comment: Thank you for posting an explanatory answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can't update the app binary yourself, the system is responsible for updating all apps.
Though, if you just want to update some data in your app you can do that for sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I was looking for:

http://code.google.com/p/cooliris-toolkit/

It has a class called RemoteUpdater which allows me to download zip files of images/data or whatever I like to extend my content.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your needs. If you dont want to see the app you can also do an Enterprise Deploy.

Used by corporations to distribute apps to their clients or employees.

Needs a separate Apple account which costs more.

Uses same process as deploy to appstore

Archive > Distribute > create ipa/plist > copy these to webserver with html page with link to plist and user clicks on link from Safari on iOS Device and it installs.

Going back to CArpp Store review process after that is painful.